# My XML sitemap contains spam content, while the HTML sitemap is not. What can I do?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, hacked-site

My website just recovered from an attack. I find out that [my XML sitemap](https://qu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com/sitemap.xml) still contains spam contents:

```
<url>
<loc>http://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/7pwclknq****hux0rx.so</loc>
<lastmod>2020-04-13</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/a0***u</loc>
<lastmod>2020-04-13</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com/mp412******msm2ayay</loc>
<lastmod>2020-04-13</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

However, [my HTML sitemap](https://qu%E1%BA%A3c%E1%BA%A7u.com/sitemap.html) is clean.

I'm using the [Google (XML) Sitemaps Generator](https://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/) for WordPress, but it doesn't have a "refresh" or "reindex" button.

Is there a way to deal with this? And why can the attacker be able to change my sitemap? Assuming they don't have my FTP password.

Comment: Have you deleted the xml sitemap file so it can be rebuilt from scratch?  Not only will that give you a fresh sitemap, but if the spam content is there, you will know it is still in your site.

Answer (score 1):

1. First scan your website using https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/  and see if you have any malicious code in your website.
2. Once its clean, try to remove the old xml file and then reinstall Google XML plugin to create a fresh sitemap.

I hope it helps, if there is still an issue do post here.